# how to merge two objects with same values?

Tags: java, swing, background, jbutton

I have two color objects.

```
 public static Color BUTT_BGS = new Color(200, 162, 232);
 public static Color BUTT_BGB = new Color(0, 162, 232);
```

These color objects used for buttons. Now I feel to make all button to one color.

```
public static Color BUTT_SBG = new Color(0, 162, 232);
public static Color BUTT_BG = new Color(0, 162, 232);
```

Instead of two objects I want make one object. If I delete one object then I have to rename every where in total application, like more than 200 button i need to change.

I am asking, is there any alternative way to do that.

Comment: *"I want make one object"* -- do you really have so many different color variations so memory consumption becomes critical? besides that, why these colors supposed to be constants, aren't `final`?

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Ya your right i have to declare them as final, I didn't think so.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou I have these two objects only for buttons background color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
public static Color BUTT_SBG = new Color(0, 162, 232);
//public static Color BUTT_BG = new Color(0, 162, 232); comment it
public static Color BUTT_BG =BUTT_SBG;
```

now `BUTT_BG` is referenced to `BUTT_SBG` color.

Comment: I can do so but in Every where I need to change Button.setBackGround(BUTT_BG)  I don't want to do this.

Comment: @shimbushambu nope .you don't need to change .you can use `Button.setBackGround(BUTT_SBG)` also .both have same effect

Comment: Ok this is working fine thank you. But what about memory allocation for the object

Comment: @shimbushambu if you want to remove one color completely  you can use built in functions of your ide.search and replace will do it.you can replace all `BUTT_BG` with `BUTT_SBG` so you don't need to do one by one

Comment: IDE will give error because variable name conflict.

Comment: @shimbushambu you can do it.but you don't need .just a one another variable not going to change performance or memory .